# Filter "AND" in Parse Server

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to know if there is a way to use an "AND" filter in a query on the parse server. In my case, I would like to filter posts by categories, for example, I have a colum "tags" (an array), and there, all the tags that are related to that post are. I retrieve the tags that the user is intersted with, and then I query to find posts that contain any of those tags ...

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
  ArrayList<String> tags = (ArrayList<String>)object.get("myTags");
  query.whereContainedIn("tags", tags);
```

The problem with this query is that it brings very vague answers, for example, a user follows a "Curiosities" tag, and also follows the tag "Avengers", I want to show it first, posts that contain these 2 tags, not only one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereContainedIn` will find objects where a particular key's contains *one of* the elements in the passed array.

To get objects where a particular key contains *all of* the elements in a passed array, use `whereContainedAll`.

Note, though, if you're aim is to list matches in order, where objects matching *all* tags are listed first, followed by objects matching *some* tags.  Then you'll need to query with the more permissive version (`whereContainedIn`) and do the sort -- sorting by matching tag count -- on the client.

Comment: Hello, "whereContainedAl"l was exactly what I wanted, and thanks for the note, I'm sure it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to Parse Server docs..

```
String[] names = {"Jonathan Walsh", "Dario Wunsch", "Shawn Simon"};
query.whereContainedIn("playerName", Arrays.asList(names));
```

https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#query-constraints

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but as you can see, I'm already doing this in the example I put in the question. And as informed, this search filters through fields that contain one or more tags.

Comment: what is the .size() of tags ... Or, better yet, print out the items in tags before your query.whereContainedIn..

Comment: This varies from user to user, they can choose how many tags are available, and the posts contain tags that are related to it.
Example: A post that says some curiosity about avengers (movie) may have the tags, curiosity and avengers related to this post.

Comment: thats fine... are you a user in your app...you need to test this one way or another.... doesnt look like you tested your code. debug it and step through the code... i would guess thats tags.size() is empty.

Comment: I think maybe you have not understood, category search works. I will give another example, in this case we have 2 posts, post A and post B. and we have a user D. User D is interested in the following category, Batman, Internet and android.
Post A, contain the tag "batman" .
Post B contains the tag, "internet" and "android".
I want to show user D, post B first, because it is theoretically more relevant to the user, since post B contains two tags that are of interest to the user.

Comment: oh, i understand. you are still not answering my question, what is the size of tags.size()? you are setting whereContained, but is this list is empty.... then it will never work... get me?

Comment: tags,size() = 5

Comment: debug your code... print tags . System.out.println(tags); does it print the proper tags?